# How to connect Spring Boot Application with MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new at `spring` framework, I want to connect my `MySQL` database which located in `localhost` with spring boot application.

Comment: you can add the database configuration in application.properties

Comment: Hi Appel, welcome to stackoverflow. kindly provide details on what you have done so far.

Comment: Give yourself a nice try and search for relevant post before posting. There are numerous question here about this. Welcome :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm listing out the minimal configuration:

In pom.xml

```
<!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

You can get such examples everywhere. Prefer to read https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Source : https://spring.io

Checkout other questions too :

[How to use Spring Boot with MySQL database and JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981789/how-to-use-spring-boot-with-mysql-database-and-jpa)

[Spring Boot MYSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500338/spring-boot-mysql-connection)

[Spring boot - MySQL settings are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247283/spring-boot-mysql-settings-are-not-working)

Comment: How can i see table created by the application?

Comment: Well, in that case use mysql workbench and use the localhost with port 3306 and then you can connect to the database and see the schema created

Answer (score 0):

To connect with mysql need some dependencies as below

Dependencies (maven -> pom.xml).

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

in `application.properties` need some extra configuration setting which must like like

application.properties (src/main/resources/application.properties)

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database 
# connection. In this example we have "netgloo_blog" as database name and 
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/database_name
spring.datasource.username = mysql-userId
spring.datasource.password = mysql-pwd

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy (Not necessary to add but you can use this too)
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Now your `EntityManager` Object will be constructed when you starts your spring boot Configuration.

Above defined configuration is enough to connect your local my-sql database but here is some more configuration that you need to make your code more readable.

Enable JPARepositories such that CRUD Repositories must defined in a defined package.

Add `@EnableJPARepositories("basepackage.*")` to your `SpringBootMainApplicationClass` like this..

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJPARepositories("com.demo.application.*.repositories")
@ComponentScan("com.demo.application.*")
public class SpringBootMainApplicationClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainApplicationClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

by adding `@EnableJPARepositories` Annotation in `MainClass` enables user to make your code more readable and `EntityManager` Object only restricted to only defined package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add database configuration properties for Mysql in your application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=mysql
spring.datasource.password=mysql
```

1. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` this configuration will create tables based on your entities which were created by you.
2. `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example` this configuration connects through jdbc to your database called db_example. You need to create that database.
3. `spring.datasource.username=mysql` this configuration you need to put your user who will connect via jdbc to your mysql database.
4. `spring.datasource.password=mysql` this configuration you need to provide your password which is represented by your user in order to connect through jdbc to your mysql database.

In addition tou you need to add dependencies for Mysql and JPA.

- If you are using maven, add the dependencies in your pom.xml:

  ```
  <dependencies>
      <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```
- If you are using gradle, add the dependencies in build.gradle:

  ```
  dependencies {
      // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
      compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

      // Use MySQL Connector-J
      compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java' 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependencies in `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add below database properties in application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

For more details please refer this [**link**](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.15'
```